# ActiveMQ Artemis cluster with 3 pairs master/slave java configuration url

Tags: java, spring-jms, high-availability, activemq-artemis

I have ACtiveMQ Artemis with HA configuration as Replication with cluster of brokers 3 masters and 3 slaves for each master. They are running on 6 different machines.

I would like to know how will look like Broker URL ? Should I use all 6 brokers or should I use only masters in the boker url ?

```java
ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("(tcp://amq1:61616,tcp://amq2:61616,tcp://amq3:61616,tcp://amq4:61616,tcp://amq5:61616,tcp://amq6:61616)?ha=true&retryInterval=1000&retryIntervalMultiplier=1.0&reconnectAttempts=-1");
```

`broker.xml` for a master

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>amq1</name>
      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
      <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>
      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>
      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>
      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>
      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>
      <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>
      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
      <journal-buffer-timeout>28000</journal-buffer-timeout>
      <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>^
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>
      <max-disk-usage>100</max-disk-usage>
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
      <critical-analyzer-timeout>150000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
      <page-sync-timeout>1628000</page-sync-timeout>
      <global-max-size>204Mb</global-max-size>

      <connectors>
        <connector name="amq1">tcp://amq1:61616</connector>
        <connector name="amq2">tcp://amq2:61616</connector>
        <connector name="amq3">tcp://amq3:61616</connector>
        <connector name="amq4">tcp://amq4:61616</connector>
        <connector name="amq5">tcp://amq5:61616</connector>
        <connector name="amq6">tcp://amq6:61616</connector>
      </connectors>
       <acceptors>
           <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
           <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
           <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
           <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
           <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
       </acceptors>
       <broadcast-groups>
           <broadcast-group name="artemis-broadcast-group">
               <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
               <group-port>9876</group-port>
               <broadcast-period>2000</broadcast-period>
               <connector-ref>amq1</connector-ref>
           </broadcast-group>
       </broadcast-groups>
       <discovery-groups>
           <discovery-group name="artemis-discovery-group">
               <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
               <group-port>9876</group-port>
               <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
           </discovery-group>
       </discovery-groups>
      <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>
      <cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>
      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="artemis-cluster">
            <connector-ref>amq1</connector-ref>
            <retry-interval>1000</retry-interval>
            <retry-interval-multiplier>3</retry-interval-multiplier>
            <max-retry-interval>5000</max-retry-interval>
            <initial-connect-attempts>-1</initial-connect-attempts>
            <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
            <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
            <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
             <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="artemis-discovery-group"/>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
      
      <!-- Other config -->
      <ha-policy>
        <replication>
          <master>
            <group-name>artemis-group-1</group-name>
            <quorum-vote-wait>12</quorum-vote-wait>
            <vote-on-replication-failure>true</vote-on-replication-failure>
            <!--for auto failback -->
            <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
          </master>
        </replication>
      </ha-policy>

      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>
      <addresses>
         <address name="exampleQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="exampleQueue"/>
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="DLQ">
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
      </addresses>
      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <auto-create-dead-letter-resources>true</auto-create-dead-letter-resources>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <address-setting match="exampleQueue">            
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>                      
            <redelivery-delay>1000</redelivery-delay>    
            <max-delivery-attempts>3</max-delivery-attempts>
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <page-size-bytes>1048576</page-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
        </address-setting>
      </address-settings>
   </core>
</configuration>
```

`broker.xml` for a slave

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>amq2</name>
      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
      <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>
      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>
      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>
      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>
      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>
      <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>
      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
      <journal-buffer-timeout>28000</journal-buffer-timeout>
      <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>
      <max-disk-usage>100</max-disk-usage>
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
      <critical-analyzer-timeout>150000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
      <page-sync-timeout>1628000</page-sync-timeout>
      <global-max-size>204Mb</global-max-size>

      <connectors>
        <connector name="amq1">tcp://amq1:61616</connector>
        <connector name="amq2">tcp://amq2:61616</connector>
        <connector name="amq3">tcp://amq3:61616</connector>
        <connector name="amq4">tcp://amq4:61616</connector>
        <connector name="amq5">tcp://amq5:61616</connector>
        <connector name="amq6">tcp://amq6:61616</connector>
      </connectors>
       <acceptors>
           <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
           <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
           <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
           <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
           <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
       </acceptors>
       <broadcast-groups>
           <broadcast-group name="artemis-broadcast-group">
               <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
               <group-port>9876</group-port>
               <broadcast-period>2000</broadcast-period>
               <connector-ref>amq2</connector-ref>
           </broadcast-group>
       </broadcast-groups>
       <discovery-groups>
           <discovery-group name="artemis-discovery-group">
               <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
               <group-port>9876</group-port>
               <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
           </discovery-group>
       </discovery-groups>
      <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>
      <cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>
      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="artemis-cluster">
            <connector-ref>amq2</connector-ref>
            <retry-interval>1000</retry-interval>
            <retry-interval-multiplier>3</retry-interval-multiplier>
            <max-retry-interval>5000</max-retry-interval>
            <initial-connect-attempts>-1</initial-connect-attempts>
            <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
            <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
            <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
             <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="artemis-discovery-group"/>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
      
      <!-- Other config -->
      <ha-policy>
        <replication>
          <slave>
            <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
            <failback-delay>5000</failback-delay>
          </slave>
        </replication>
      </ha-policy>

      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>
      <addresses>
         <address name="exampleQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="exampleQueue"/>
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="DLQ">
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
      </addresses>
      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <auto-create-dead-letter-resources>true</auto-create-dead-letter-resources>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <address-setting match="exampleQueue">            
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>                      
            <redelivery-delay>1000</redelivery-delay>    
            <max-delivery-attempts>3</max-delivery-attempts>
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <page-size-bytes>1048576</page-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
        </address-setting>
      </address-settings>
   </core>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache ActiveMQ Artemis clients receive knowledge of all live and backup servers after connecting, so that in event of connection failure at the client - live server connection, the client will detect this and reconnect to the backup server. This means that using only masters in the boker url could work but what would happen if none of the masters is live?

The client would not be able to connect, so **adding the backups to the boker url would allow the client to connect when none of the masters is live.**